# ASP variable doesnt output from its tags

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have got this code..which is part of an overall code.

```
    <%
dim rsFav
sSQL = "(SELECT shorthand, display, larry_ranking, site_url FROM larrydb_site_list lsl JOIN larrydb_review lr on lsl.sid = lr.sid WHERE display=true AND niche='regular' ORDER BY larry_ranking DESC Limit 2) UNION (SELECT shorthand, display, larry_ranking, site_url FROM larrydb_site_list lsl JOIN larrydb_review lr on lsl.sid = lr.sid WHERE display=true AND niche='regular' AND shorthand='sexier')"
Set rsFav = objConn.Execute(sSQL)
While NOT rsFav.EOF
%>
        <tr><td>

                    <div style="background-image:url('images/<%=LCase(rsFav("shorthand"))%>_icon.png')" border="0" class="fav_site_icon">
                    <a href="http://livecamdeals.com/review.asp?sitename=<%=LCase(rsFav("shorthand"))%>"></a>
                    </div>
                    </td><td>
                    <a href='<%=LCase(rsFav("site_url"))%>' title="Visit <%=LCase(rsFav("shorthand"))%>.com" target="_blank" class="visit_site_icon <%=LCase(rsFav("shorthand"))%> special_<%=LCase(rsFav("shorthand"))%>"></a>
                    </td>
                    </tr></td>
<%
rsFav.MoveNext
wEnd
%>
```

Everything works fine..apart this line..

\
I get the site name as empty:

Why is that? I know nothing about asp..I know php & asp.net .only

UPDATE: this is what I get:

HTML output. Example of one link:

```
<div style="background-image:url('images/.png')" border="0" class="fav_site_icon">



                </div>
```

Notice, above..the shorthand is printed for image ..but not for link..seems to be an html problem

Comment: Can you confirm that `shorthand` actually does return values for your query?

Comment: I checked in phpmyadmin...on the server...thats what it returns when I execute the query..look above

Comment: can you add the html output if the answer below does not resolve your issue?

Comment: Can you paste the `view-source` of the page?

Comment: It's impossible to reproduce this issue with the sample code you provided - it runs without any problems on my machine. I suspect there's something different in the html code you run on your machine.

Comment: no..I had to put it in a variable..see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable to be the value returned by rsFav("shorthand")) and reference that instead through throughout your code.

```
Dim shortHandId
While NOT rsFav.EOF 
shortHandId = rsFav("shorthand")
%>         
<tr><td>                      
<div style="background-image:url('images/<%=LCase(shortHandId)%>_icon.png')" border="0" class="fav_site_icon">                     
<a href="http://livecamdeals.com/review.asp?sitename=<%=LCase(shortHandId)%>"></a>                     
</div>                     
</td>
<td>                     
<a href='<%=LCase(rsFav("site_url"))%>' title="Visit <%=LCase(shortHandId)%>.com" target="_blank" class="visit_site_icon <%=LCase(shortHandId)%> special_<%=LCase(shortHandId)%>"></a>                     
</td>                     
</tr>
```

Comment: could have be something to do with Column values being affected by the union but glad it works

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<a href="http://example.com/review.asp?sitename=<%=LCase(rsFav("shorthand"))%>">
```

into

```
<a href='http://example.com/review.asp?sitename=<%=LCase(rsFav("shorthand"))%>'>
```

to have your `href` use single quotes.

Comment: it doesnt throw an error either.. I doesn work on siteurl..I put the query in phpmyadmin..it retrieves everything with no empty fields

Comment: it does output them..when i take them outside the link...I think it is an html problem